# Processing file with VM endpoint

Tags: mule

I'm trying to read a large file in chunks, create a list of the chunked data, and send it to a VM to further process. So for example I have 9 emails in a file and I want to process 3 at a time and put the list of 3 emails on a VM (each as a message payload):

> [email01@gmail.com, email02@gmail.com, email03@gmail.com]
>   [email04@gmail.com, email05@gmail.com, email06@gmail.com] 
>   [email07@gmail.com, email08@gmail.com, email09@gmail.com]

```
<flow name="flow1" doc:name="flow1">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="emailList" moveToDirectory="processedEmails" pollingFrequency="60000" doc:name="EmailList" connector-ref="File">
        <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="*.txt" caseSensitive="true" />
    </file:inbound-endpoint>

    <component class="org.sample.component.EmailAddressFileReader" doc:name="chunk email addresses and send to VM" />
</flow>

<flow name="process" doc:name="process">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="in" doc:name="VM"/>
    <logger message="payload is: #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>   
</flow>
```

#### My EmailAddressFileReader.java component:

```
public class EmailAddressFileReader implements Callable{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailAddressFileReader.class);

    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {

        InputStream fileStream = (InputStream) eventContext.getMessage().getPayload();
        DataInputStream ds = new DataInputStream(fileStream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ds));

        MuleClient muleClient = eventContext.getMuleContext().getClient();

        String emailAddress;
        List<String> emailAddressList = new ArrayList<String>();

        while ((emailAddress = br.readLine()) != null) {
            emailAddressList.add(emailAddress);
            if(emailAddressList.size() > 2) {
                muleClient.dispatch("vm://in", emailAddressList, null);
                logger.info("after dispatch to vm: " + emailAddressList);
                emailAddressList.clear();//???
            }           
        }
        fileStream.close();
        logger.info("chuncked email address file");
        return null;
    }
}
```

I don't know how to process and send to the VM just 3 (in this example). If I remove the list.clear() I get all the emails in the list [email01, email02...mail09] and when I have the clear() I get an empty list as my payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I think to send messages from a component it is not a good idea. It makes the flow less readable given that it would do unexpecting things for an external reader.

If you really really want to do it, use a [component binding](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Component+Bindings).

However I would recommend either:

- Use [Mule Batch](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Batch+Processing) it you have an EE license.
- Create a transformer that transform the input stream into an iterator of List and then concatenate a foreach.
- Create a custom splitter for the InputStream to a number of List

Comment: thanks for the input Victor, I've changed my flow to use foreach:    '<flow name="adhocEmailFlow" doc:name="adhocEmailFlow">
  <foreach batchSize="1500" doc:name="for each email list">
   <custom-transformer class="com.mycompany.transformer.Another" doc:name="Java"/>
   <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
   <logger message="json: #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
   <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="https://some.external.service.com" doc:name="HTTP"></https:outbound-endpoint>
  </foreach>
 </flow>'

Answer (score -1):

```
List<String> emailAddressList = new ArrayList<String>();

        while ((emailAddress = br.readLine()) != null) {
            emailAddressList.add(emailAddress);
            if(emailAddressList.size() > 2) {
                muleClient.dispatch("vm://in", emailAddressList, null);
                logger.info("after dispatch to vm: " + emailAddressList);
                emailAddressList = new ArrayList<String>();
            }           
        }
```

Comment: thank you, that worked. However, I still don't understand why clearing the list and sending it with different items vs. creating a new list works.